# QGIS legend formatting upon export

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I am creating some maps to include with my research thesis at the end of the year.

When I export my layouts that I have made in QGIS 3.28, I have a problem with SVG formatting. When I open the exported images in my image browser, everything looks exactly as intended. However, when I import the image into my Word doc, the font formatting in the legends changes. The text is unchanged in the labels on the maps themselves, but the legends changed to a font other than the one I specified in my layout.

Just as a note - I tried exporting all my layouts as JPEG images instead, but after I insert the image into my Word doc, all the text becomes noticeably aliased, even when I'm exporting at 300 dpi.

Answer (score 2):

I have figured out the issue! The font that I was using for my legend and labels was installed in whichever folder QGIS refers to for typefaces. However, the font was not installed in my system fonts folder within Windows.

I downloaded the font family from Google Fonts and installed it. The problem seems to have resolved itself now.